The process started from Chrome location Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed
I'm trying to make a driver of my own profile to enter website with captcha, but I got a strange error, my driver version is same as Chrome version.
This is my code:
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

    user_data_dir = r"C:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
    profile =r"C:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
    options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory=Default")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

    service = Service(r'.\chromedriver.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

This is the error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\seleniums.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
    File "C:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
    File "C:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
    File "C:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Users\umair\Documents\selenium-teetime\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
    (chrome not reachable)
    (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
    Stacktrace:

I want to create a ChromeDriver session with my profile.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

make sure chromedriver and chrome major versions match.  Don't set debugging port unless you already have a debugging session you want to attach to with the same port.  (so something like running the site in an IDE) Create a new profile manually and then use that.  (I'm not sure using the default profile works...)
